# WebGL - two different approaches to Point Light: what is the difference?

Tags: shaders, lighting, webgl

So I'm studying Webgl and after directional light I'm approaching point light.

So I've seen two different approaches:

1. Take the directional light (diffuse and specular components) and multiply them by a falloff attenuation, for example with the [attenuation function is by Tom Madams](https://imdoingitwrong.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/improved-light-attenuation/) that anyway take in account the distance from the fragment surface point to the light point. This approach is spotted in this [webgl light walkthrough tutorial](https://github.com/stackgl/glsl-lighting-walkthrough), and I find it easier to understand. Seems also the same approach from this [OpenGL tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Multiple-lights) (in the section Point Light)
2. The other approach listed [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-point.html) does not involve a light attenuation falloff but calculate the light direction from any fragment position and the light point source. It seems a little bit more complicated to me.

Is there something that I have totally misunderstood? What is the difference between this two approaches? When to use the first and when to use the second?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter isn't point lighting in the traditional sense and also discusses Phong shading (that's where the complication comes from mostly, it's a simpler approach by default). It will lighten up a surface if it's facing in the direction of the point, regardless of distance. It works similarly to stars (e.g. the Sun), while the former imitates a desk lamp

Comment: Hi @Bálint, thanks for the answer, but can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @nkint which part?

Comment: Note that the Sun experiences inverse-square falloff due to diverging light rays too — just over longer scales. We can approximate the sunlight falling on Earth as a directional light source with no falloff, but if we wanted to reach out to Pluto in the same scene we'd definitely want to factor in directional divergence & distance falloff. ;)

Comment: Hi @Bálint . In the second link, I'm referring to this first example that has no phong: https://tinyurl.com/yxtgrmjw So, what is that? I understand that the directional is like the Sun and the point light is like a bulb, but I'm still confused.. Where can I find a clear definition of what is a point light? Considering only the diffuse component (no specular, no phong, no reflection), what is the difference between a diffuse and a point lights other then falloff attenuation?

Comment: and you comment is clear thanks @DMGregory

Comment: @nkint that does have phong. It's just a shading technique to simulate how real life looks like to some extent by combining fake ambient lighting with fake ray scattering and fake specular lighting, but is waaay faster than "modern" solutions (it makes objects look kind of metallic or plasticy on my opinion)